# Select multiple indices in an axis of pytorch tensor

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pytorch, tensor

My actual problem is in a higher dimension, but I am posting it in a smaller dimension to make it easy to visualize.

I have a tensor of shape (2,3,4):
`x = torch.randn(2, 3, 4)`

```
tensor([[[-0.9118,  1.4676, -0.4684, -0.6343],
         [ 1.5649,  1.0218, -1.3703,  1.8961],
         [ 0.8652,  0.2491, -0.2556,  0.1311]],

        [[ 0.5289, -1.2723,  2.3865,  0.0222],
         [-1.5528, -0.4638, -0.6954,  0.1661],
         [-1.8151, -0.4634,  1.6490,  0.6957]]])
```

From this tensor, I need to select rows given by a list of indices along `axis-1`.

Example,

```
indices = torch.tensor([0, 2])
```

**Expected Output:**

```
tensor([[[-0.9118,  1.4676, -0.4684, -0.6343]],
        [[-1.8151, -0.4634,  1.6490,  0.6957]]])
```

Output Shape: `(2,1,4)`

**Explanation:** Select 0th row from x[0], select 2nd row from x[1]. (Came from indices)

I tried using `index_select` like this:

```
torch.index_select(x, 1, indices)
```

But the problem is that it is selecting the 0th and 2nd row for each item in x. It looks like it needs some modification I could not figure it out at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, this is quite straightforward. An easy way to navigate through two dimensions *in parallel* is to use a range on the first axis and your indexing tensor on the second:

```
>>> x[range(len(indices)), indices]
tensor([[-0.9118,  1.4676, -0.4684, -0.6343],
        [-1.8151, -0.4634,  1.6490,  0.6957]])
```

---

In more general cases though, this would require the use of [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

- First expand indices such that it has enough dimensions:

  ```
  index = indices[:,None,None].expand(x.size(0), -1, x.size(-1))
  ```
- Then you can apply the function on `x` and `index` and squeeze `dim=1`:

  ```
  >>> x.gather(dim=-2, index=index)[:,0]
  tensor([[-0.9118,  1.4676, -0.4684, -0.6343],
          [-1.8151, -0.4634,  1.6490,  0.6957]])
  ```